# Kendo Chart Tooltip Template Auto Hide False

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I show tooltip template in my kendo ui chart and my chart has 100% width Then When Client hover last series tooltip template overflow page left. Another problem is tooltip hide quickly , can  keep it longer time on screen and  I do not want to overflow tooltip when width is 100%. How Can I solve it? Is there Any properities autohide false?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kendo UI tooltip class like example

```
.k-tooltip-content p {
    width: 400px;
    font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    text-align: left;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

You can use all your css combination here... like this example.